# Counting the vowels in a string solution

Tags: string

I recently did a method to count the vowels in a given string and was able to solve it fairly simply, but my solution was compared to the best practices and this was the top one:

```
public class Vowels {

    public static int getCount(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]", "").length();
    }

}
```

...which is much more elegant that what i wrote and i am trying to understand it. I don't get what exactly the "(?i)[^aeiou]" part is doing. I get that it is deleting all the characters that aren't vowels but I don't understand what the operators are doing or why they work in quotes shouldn't the program just see it as a string?

Answer (score 1):

This is a regex and it is basically ignoring the case because we are only providing set of `[aeiou]` but it should also match with the capital ones `[AEIOU]`. Then `^` symbol is used to replace all the characters with empty string `""` except for vowels(irrespective of their case).

```
(?i)   - starts case-insensitive mode

(?-i)  - turns off case-insensitive mode

[^...] - NOT ONE of these characters.
```